# PHP add key value to array with each loop iteration

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array from which I want to create a new array with key value pairs. I think I know what's required, I just need some help with the syntax.

```
foreach ($stuff as $thing){
    $thing1 = $thing->prop1;
    $thing2 = $thing->prop2;
    // this is where I need to set $newstuff = array($thing1 => $thing2);
    $newstuff[] = ??
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `array_map()` instead of `foreach()`. Example:

```
$newstuff = array_map(function($v){return array($v->prop1=>$v->prop2);}, $stuff);
```

And using `foreach()`:

```
foreach ($stuff as $thing){
    $newstuff[] = array($thing->prop1=>$thing->prop2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
foreach ($stuff as $thing){
    $thing1 = $thing->prop1;
    $thing2 = $thing->prop2;
    // this is where I need to set $newstuff = array($thing1 => $thing2);
    $newstuff[$thing1] = $thing2;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$newstuff = array();
foreach ($stuff in $thing) {
   $newstuff[$thing->prop1] = $thing->prop2; 
}
```

or

```
$newstuff = array();
foreach ($stuff in $thing) {
   $newstuff[] = array($thing->prop1, $thing->prop2); 
}
```

All depends if you want to save in a array or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newstuff = array();
foreach ($stuff as $thing){
    $thing1 = $thing->prop1;
    $thing2 = $thing->prop2;
    // this is where I need to set $newstuff = array($thing1 => $thing2);
    $newstuff[] = array($thing1 => $thing2);
}
```

or

```
$newstuff = array();
foreach ($stuff as $thing){
    $thing1 = $thing->prop1;
    $thing2 = $thing->prop2;
    // this is where I need to set $newstuff = array($thing1 => $thing2);
    $newstuff[$thing1] = $thing2;
}
```

depends on desired result...